# How to select which div to display by id?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code written like this. I would like the myDIV1 to display when I click the first section with 'HELLO' quote, and myDIV2 when second section 'HI' is clicked. 
Tried using event.target to change javascript var X into myDIV1 or myDIV2 but not so sure if my syntax used is correct or if the logic I tried can be possible.

I would like to change var x = document.getElementbyId( *'either of the two divs here'* ) 
   when 1st section or 2nd section is click. (sorry for the bad grammar)

html

```
<section class="news"> HELLO
</section>

<section class="news"> HI
</section>

<div class="divelement "id="myDIV1">
    This is my DIV1 element.
</div>

<div class="divelement "id="myDIV2">
    This is my DIV2 element.
```

javascript

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "block";
        } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this way using jQuery.

```js
jQuery('.news').click(function(){
var target = jQuery(this).attr('data-target');
jQuery('.divelement').hide(); /*hide all divelement*/
jQuery(target).toggle(); /*Show the targeted divelement*/
console.log('Show' + target);
});
```

```css
.divelement{
  display: none; /* By default divelement will be hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="news" data-target="#myDIV1"> HELLO
</section> <!-- set targeted div id in data-target attribute -->

<section class="news" data-target="#myDIV2"> HI
</section>

<div class="divelement "id="myDIV1">
    This is my DIV1 element.
</div>

<div class="divelement "id="myDIV2">
    This is my DIV2 element.
</div>
```

Comment: I placed all the codes to their respective places (I guess) but the output it showed to me is like this.  HI HELLO I don't know if I placed it wrong or if I gave the wrong code to begin with. Thanks for the help though I'll keep trying to study the code.

Comment: @nekoneko click "Run Code Snippet" - it works) Something gone wrong in your code...

Comment: Yes I did click run code snippet, as well as integrate the code in my project, however the result remains the same, dont know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need id-s at all. Can make simple tabs with already existing classes:

```js
let news = document.querySelectorAll('.news');
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.divelement');
// saved element lists to variables
// `news[0]` — the first element, `news[1]` — second, etc. 

let prev = 0; // index of previous clicked section

for( let i = 0; i < news.length; i++ ){
  // Google → for loop, JS for loop let

  news[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    news[prev].classList.remove('active');
    divs[prev].classList.remove('active');
    // removing class from last section and div
    
    news[i].classList.add('active');
    divs[i].classList.add('active');
    // adding to current clicked, by index ( `i` - exact number, got from `for` )
    
    prev = i; // updating previous clicked index
  });
}
```

```css
.divelement {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.news { cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; }

.divelement.active {
  display: block;
}

.news.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="news">HELLO</section>
<section class="news">HI</section>
<section class="news">BUBU</section>

<div class="divelement">HELLO</div>
<div class="divelement">HI</div>
<div class="divelement">BUBU</div>
```

If you are 100% sure, that there will be only two elements, can use such trick:

```js
let news = document.querySelectorAll('.news');
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.divelement');

setDivToggle(0);
setDivToggle(1);

function setDivToggle(index) {
  news[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let hide = +!index; // (*1)   
    
    divs[index].style.display = "block";  
    divs[hide].style.display = "none";  
  });
}
```

```css
.news { cursor: pointer; margin: 10px; }
.divelement { display: none; }
```

```html
<section class="news"> HELLO </section>
<section class="news"> HI </section>

<div class="divelement"id="myDIV1">DIV1 element.</div>
<div class="divelement"id="myDIV2">DIV2 element.</div>
```

**(*1)** `let hide = +!index;` — clicked index always will be `0` or `1`.

In boolean expressions, `0 == false, 1 == true`.

`!` — logical "NOT" operator. Converts `false → true` and vice versa.

`+` converts the result into number.

Little demo:

```js
console.log( +false ) // 0
console.log( +true ) // 1

console.log( !0 ) // true
console.log( !1 ) // false

console.log( +!0 ) // 1
console.log( +!1 ) // 0
```

In fact, it's just twisting 1 with 0 and 0 with 1.